# Display Nested JSON data in SAPUI5 (sap.m Table)

Tags: json, mobile, data-binding, sapui5

i currently work with **sap.m** and i have a problem with binding data of a **nested json** to a **sap.m table**.

This is the content of my json file:

```
{
 "courses": [

  {
   "req_id": "1",
   "name" : "ABAP OO Basics",
   "start" : "20-08-2014",
   "end" : "22-08-2014",
   "starttime": "10:00:00",
   "endtime": "16:00:00",
   "status": "Booked",
   "room": "Room CDE",
   "adress" : "Adress No.1",
   "street": "Street No.1",
   "zip_code": "74892142578485",
   "city": "City No.1",
   "country": "Country No.1",
   "phone": "0595726764675435497436497",
   "fax":"12",
   "cap_min": "10",
   "cap_opt": "20",
   "cap_max": "30",
   "img": "./res/1.jpg",
   "content": "Test",  
   "participant":  [{   "firstname": "Maik",
                        "lastname": "Maier",
                        "job": "installer",
                        "company": "muster" 
                    },
                    {   "firstname": "Marco",
                        "lastname": "Schmidt",
                        "job": "installer",
                        "company": "schmitt" 
                    },
                    {   "firstname": "Hans",
                        "lastname": "Mueller",
                        "job": "installer",
                        "company": "muster" 
                    },
                    {   "firstname": "Matthias",
                        "lastname": "Gottlieb",
                        "job": "installer",
                        "company": "schmitt" 
                    }]

  }
 ]
}
```

This is the code that creates my table and binds the data:

```
var oTable = new sap.m.Table("idRandomDataTable", {
            headerToolbar : new sap.m.Toolbar({
                content : [ new sap.m.Label({
                    text : "Participant List"
                }), new sap.m.ToolbarSpacer({}), new sap.m.Button("idPersonalizationButton", {
                    icon : "sap-icon://person-placeholder"
                }) ]
            }),
            columns : [ 
                new sap.m.Column({
                width : "2em",
                header : new sap.m.Label({
                    text : "Firstname"
                })
                }), 
                new sap.m.Column({
                width : "2em",
                header : new sap.m.Label({
                    text : "Lastname"
                })
                }), 
                new sap.m.Column({
                width : "2em",
                header : new sap.m.Label({
                    text : "Job"
                })
                }), 
                new sap.m.Column({
                width : "2em",
                header : new sap.m.Label({
                    text : "Company"
                })
                })
                ]
        });


        var oModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

        var model = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
        var aData = model.getProperty("/courses");

        oModel1.setData({

            modelData : aData

        });

        oTable.setModel(oModel1);

        oTable.bindItems("/modelData", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells : [ new sap.m.Text({

                text : {
                    path: "participant.'firstname'",
                }
            }), new sap.m.Text({
                text : "{participant/lastname}"
            }), new sap.m.Text({
                text : "{participant}.{job}",
            }), new sap.m.Text({
                text : "{street}",
            }),]
        }));
```

I want to bind the content of the property "participant" - which is a subproperty of "courses" to a sap m table and i can't get it work (i have tried many things and searched a long time but i found no solution and i don't know how to access the json in this case).

This is what i see in my browser (you can see that the property street is displayed but for participant i can't get the data):

```
Firstname    Lastname    Job              Company
                      [object Object],  Street No.1
                      [object Object],
                      [object Object],
                      [object Object].
```

It would be a great help if anyone has a hint for my issue.

Thanks a lot,

Regards,

Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you didn't post all of your code. So I'm making a couple of assumptions which make sense in the context of what you have posted:

You're assigning the JSON to the default (unnamed) model on the core:

```
sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
  "courses": [
    {
      "req_id": "1",
      ...
});
```

If you've done this, then this bit of your code will work:

```
var model = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();
  var aData = model.getProperty("/courses");
  oModel1.setData({
    modelData : aData
  });
```

So now we get to the crux of the matter. You want to bind the table rows to the participants of the course you showed in the JSON (the first and only course instance). You need to know that binding an aggregation such as the items of a table should be related to an array, rather than (what you did) to an object. So if you bind it to the participant property, which points to an array ... and also get the binding syntax right ... you're good:

```
    oTable.bindItems("/modelData/0/participant", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells : [ new sap.m.Text({

            text : {
                path: "firstname",
            }
        }), new sap.m.Text({
            text : "{lastname}"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
            text : "{job}",
        }), new sap.m.Text({
            text : "{company}",
        }),]
    }));
```

Comment: Hi qmacro, thanks for your good answer, i can see data now but how does this work if i have more than one course, i just set 2 courses in my json but i now get always displayed the participants of the first course for both courses. (sorry for not posting all my code but its quite a lot)

Comment: By the way i also read this topic where the author is also binding the subobject and that works but for me it did not apply - http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/08/02/creating-sapui5-applications-based-on-public-json-apis-or-web-services.

Comment: You didn't ask about multiple courses, and the code you posted didn't allow for that situation. We addressed the specific qustion you asked. Naturally this will be a requirement at a higher level, but you need to work out how you want to display things; right now you only have a single table for participants of one course.

Comment: My approach is that i have a sap m split app where i can select courses and i get the details for the course among others a table with participants of each course. What do you mean with my code does not allow for that situation? I have the data in my json model so it must be possible to display them right? ;)

Comment: I mean the code you showed us doesn't allow for that. No sign of the splitapp. But you're on the right track, you just need to make sure you assign the right binding context to the detail.

Comment: Hm i know what you mean but i still don't get it all as i think i have the binding context already, i edited my initial post, there u will find my view and controller code... am i missing something?

Comment: This is worthy of a new question. Please re-edit and accept the appropriate answer, then ask anew. This will help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the wrong paths.

```
oTable.bindItems("/modelData", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
        cells : [ new sap.m.Text({
            text : "{/participant/firstname}"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
            text : "{/participant/lastname}"
        }), new sap.m.Text({
            text : "{/participant/job}",
        }), new sap.m.Text({
            text : "{/participant/company}",
        }),]
    }));
```

Comment: Hi Allen, thanks for your reply. I also tried this variant by copy & paste your code but it does not work, i get an empty table, no data is displayed.